# How to read { [native code] } in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling

In my application I have class `ClassType` which takes `number` from field named `total_number` PostGreSql database and based on the size of the number `prepends M and zero's`.

Example -  `Input` to Class is `622549`

`Output` ->      `M000622549`

```
class ClassType {

    constructor(prefix, deal) {
        this._prefix  = prefix;  // a single, upper case letter
        this._deal = deal; // lowest ID number for longer padding
    }

    toString(id) {
        /* If "id" is omitted, return a string representation of this ID
         * formatter, for debugging. */
        return id ? this._prefix + ClassType.pad(id, id < this._deal ? 6 : 9)
                  : this.toString();
    }

    /* Define a stand-alone function that uses the formatting method for this ID
     * type. */
    bind2Str() { return ClassType.prototype.toString.bind(this); }
}
```

**Working Code**

I am accessing  ClassType by need to instantiate another ClassType

```
          Books.id = new ClassType("M", data["total_number"]).bind2Str();
          data['concept_id'] = new ClassType("M", data["622549"]).toString(data["total_number"]);

          console.log('Idddd', data['concept_id']); //M000622549
```

**NOT WORKING CODE- Code giving weird Output**

I want to use below approach where I can reuse the types that are already defined.

`Below Code` giving Output as `(function () { [native code] })`

```
          data['concept_id'] = Books.id.toString(data["total_number"]); 
          console.log( data['concept_id']); ----->>>>>>(function () { [native code] })
```

How can I resolve `(function () { [native code] })`?

Comment: Uhm, this is a weird question.`[native code]` cannot be read by javascript or the browser, because it's just plain, compiled browser code. There's nothing really to print but a bunch of bytes, and the browser isn't really the place to print that.

Comment: Okay if you compare my working code and not working code. Can you suggest me what changes to make? I want to reuse the existing code without reinstantiating

Comment: I think you massively overcomplicated this and I'm not really able to make heads nor tails from your code. But you `Books.id` bit is simply returning a method, so call that instead of printing it? Even if you have your own toString method, you should still call it, otherwise it will be printed as `function(){ ...your non-native code... }`. Even so this took me five minutes of staring to see, so your code should really be rethought. Nobody is ever going to be able to follow this train of thought once you are done with it.

Comment: Also pretty sure that this: `ClassType.prototype.toString.bind(this);` is just going to cause issues. You shouldn't bind to the prototype, `new` does that for you. You can remove all that and just call `new myClass( ...stuff... ).toString( id )` and it will work. This is massively overthinking things.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `bind2Str` returns a function:

```js
bind2Str() { return ClassType.prototype.toString.bind(this); }
```

The line

```js
Books.id = new ClassType("M", data["total_number"]).bind2Str();
```

then assigns that function to `Books.id` and

```js
data['concept_id'] = Books.id.toString(data["total_number"]);
```

set `data['concept_id']` to a string representation of the function.

The issue will probably be solved if you just split

```js
Books.id = new ClassType("M", data["total_number"]).bind2Str();
```

into two lines:

```js
Books.id = new ClassType("M", data["total_number"])
Books.id.bind2Str();
```

But as @somethinghere writes you seem to overcomplicate things.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood, `data['concept_id'] = Books.id.toString(data["total_number"]); 
` code does not seem to work

Comment: I have understood. `Books.id` is a function, not a `ClassType` object, so `Books.id.toString(...)` gives a string representation of a function.